# Set default face (font) with use-package ':custom-face'

Tags: fonts, use-package, customize-face

What do I need to **tell 'use-package'** so that it will **set the default font** for all frames on Emacs startup?

With 'use-package' now installed as part of Emacs, I want to specify faces with its [`:custom-face` feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/use-package.html#Faces).

(I could use `customize-face`, but the point here is to migrate this configuration to `use-package emacs` with the rest of my Emacs customisation.)

When I use `:custom-face` to specify the 'default' face for the 'emacs' package:

```lisp
;;; init.el
;; …
(use-package emacs
  ;; …
  :custom-face
  ;; Default face for any frame.
  (default ((t (:foundry "PfEd" :family "Inconsolata" :height 120))))
  ;; The basic fixed-pitch face.
  (fixed-pitch ((t (:foundry "PfEd" :family "Inconsolata" :height 120))))
  ;; …
)
```

the Inconsolata font is not used in any frame, and the 'default' face is not what `:custom-face` specified.

> <kbd>M-x</kbd> describe-face <kbd>RET</kbd> default <kbd>RET</kbd>

> ```
> Face: default (sample) (customize this face)
> …
>        Family: DejaVu Serif
>       Foundry: PfEd
>         Width: normal
>        Height: 120
> ```

The Inconsolata font is known to Emacs:

> <kbd>M-x</kbd> describe-font <kbd>RET</kbd> Inconso <kbd>RET</kbd>

> ```
> name (opened by): -PfEd-Inconsolata-medium-normal-normal-*-16-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
>        full name: Inconsolata:pixelsize=16:foundry=PfEd:weight=medium:slant=normal:width=normal:spacing=100:scalable=true
>        file name: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/inconsolata/Inconsolata.otf
> …
> ```

If I use the separate function 'set-frame-font', it works:

```lisp
;;; init.el
;; …
(use-package emacs
  ;; …
  :config
  ;; Set default font in any frame.
  (set-frame-font "Inconsolata 12" nil t)
  ;; …
  )
```

So, Emacs is not conforming to the `:custom-face` specification in `use-package emacs`, yet it knows the font and *can* set it using `set-frame-font`. It *should* obey the specification in `:custom-face`, no?

How do I use 'use-package' to specify the font for Emacs to use by default?

Comment: What happens if you just use `M-x customize-face`? If that works then check how you're using `use-package`. If that doesn't work then the problem isn't how you're using `use-package`.